# Actionscript settimeout not working

Tags: actionscript

The Timer always jumps right into the function instead of waiting 2000 milliseconds

```
stop();

var hey:Number= 2000;

function exercise(frame) {
  trace("sup");

  this.gotoAndStop(frame);
}

setTimeout(exercise(2),hey);

trace(hey);
```

Comment: Is it 2 Microseconds? Check the doc, I'm not familiar with actionscript.

Answer (score 0):

The setTimeout function (ie. not a Timer) takes the following parameters:

```
public function setTimeout(closure:Function, delay:Number, ... arguments):uint
```

Try:

```
// Save the return value so you can clear it later, otherwise your app for leak memory
var myTimeOut:uint = setTimeout(exercise, hey, 2);
trace(hey);
// the timeout closure object will not be garage collected if you do not clear it
clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
```

If you are doing this over and over, consider creating a Timer and setting/reseting the repeat count to 1 and then you can just restart the timer when need.

Comment: it says Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 15 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method clearTimeOut